# Problem with broadcom-sta-dkms after upgrading 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: upgrade, broadcom, 19.10

After upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10 something seems to have gone wrong with `broadcom-sta-dkms`.

When I run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`, it gets stuck after outputting the following (after `depmod...` nothing happens):

```
Setting up broadcom-sta-dkms (6.30.223.271-11) ...
Removing old broadcom-sta-6.30.223.271 DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  broadcom-sta
Version: 6.30.223.271
Kernel:  5.3.0-19-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

wl.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.3.0-19-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

update-initramfs......

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.30.223.271
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new broadcom-sta-6.30.223.271 DKMS files...
Building for 5.3.0-19-generic 5.3.0-050300-generic
Building initial module for 5.3.0-19-generic
This system doesn't support Secure Boot
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

wl.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
modinfo: ERROR: missing module or filename.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.3.0-19-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to get the system working again. First, doing `sudo dpkg --remove broadcom-sta-dkms` allowed `sudo apt upgrade` to run properly. After that, I removed the wireless drivers from dkms and reinstalled them. During reinstallation it again got stuck after `depmod...`. After waiting for a while I used Ctrl+C to stop the process. I thought installation hadn't gone through properly, but somehow, after rebooting, I have working wifi again.

Comment: I had a similar problem with `bcmwl-kernel-source` would be blocking the upgrade... I removed it and proceed with the upgrade. I am guessing it got included in the kernel and no longer compiles as a module.

Comment: Actually I tried removing bcmwl-kernel-source first, but that didn't work. Removing broadcom-sta-dkms is what worked in my case. That allowed the upgrade to finish, but I still had no wifi, so had to remove and reinstall the drivers.